# Find command only scanning sub folders and not only copying files from the last day

Tags: linux, cron, find, debian

I want a crontab command that at every morning checks folder /home/user/USBHD/Movies for files less then one day old and then copy them to my /home/user/NASVD/Movies with no overwriting. I tried the following but that doesn't work since it only seems to scan the subfolders and still copy all the files no matter what time they where made..

01 08 * * * /usr/bin/find /home/user/USBHD/Movies/ -mtime 1 -exec cp -n {} /home/user/NASVD/Movies \;

Anyone any idea's?

I tried the command without the cronstuff in the beginning and it didn't work as it should, like already explained.

Hope you guys can help ;)

Edit: I tried /usr/bin/find /home/user/USBHD/Movies/ -mtime +1 -exec cp -n {} /home/user/NASVD/Movies \; but that doesn't do anything at all..

EDIT::::::::::::::::::::
/usr/bin/find /home/user/USBHD/Movies/ -mtime 1 -exec cp -n {} /home/user/NASVD/Movies \;

I found the problem with this string
What it should have been:

```
 /usr/bin/find /home/user/USBHD/Movies/ -mtime '-1' -exec cp -n {} /home/user/NASVD/Movies \;
```

Thanks for helping ;D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/usr/bin/find /home/user/USBHD/Movies/ -mtime +1 -exec cp -n {} /home/user/NASVD/Movies \;
```

Two points - this will continue copying files more then 1 day old - that include 2 ,3 ,4 ... forever.  Also I hope this is run in the user's crontab so that file permissions work correctly.  If this is root's crontab the copied files will be owned by root.  This script also does not remove day 1+ and older files it just copies them.  So: as I said it will always copy any file 1+ days old.

IF you change `cp` to `mv` the file will disappear from the first directory and get moved into the second,

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much. I could not see the harm done by the crontab in root but now I see it xD. Thank you very much for that.
Is there even a single task you do need root for? Like a delete script or an unrar script?

Comment: Eay I tried your line but now it doesn't do anything.. I created a file in the folder name HIIII.txt and filled it with text but it didn't copy it to the other file.. Any idea?

Comment: Did you change the mtime on the new file to more than 24 hours ago? To do that you use the touch -t [new date] [filename] command. If this is not the case then I do not get what you want.